# Link Colors & TD / TR Hover Colors For Default Email Signatures

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I'm re editing a Branded Email Signature, and it appears to only view properly in Emails if I have the CSS as part of the HTML. `<style>any css style:;</style>` or (style.css) doesn't appear to view properly in my Email Signature.

In my added HTML code, how can I get (`a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, and `a:active`) to view at my selected colour?  :--)

And how how can I get TD or TR Hover Colour coding properly added to that HTML code?  :--)

```
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 5px solid #4169E1;">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {color: #663399;};">
         <span style="color:#663399">TEXT LINE 1</span><br><br>
         <span style="color:#4169E1">TEXT LINE 2<br>TEXT LINE 3<br>TEXT LINE 4</span><br><br>
         <span style="color:#663399">
           <a href="https://URL">TEXT LINE 5</a></span>
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why not add it as a global CSS in the head of the document? Some email clients will not read it but whichever ones does it will work.

Comment: I'll Look Up G CSS.  Thanks!  :--)

Answer (score 0):

The `:hover` is a pseudo-class selector and it only makes sense within the `<style>` tag.
There is no way you can use the `:hover` in an inline `style=""` attribute.

The only way to add the `:hover` to an element without the `<style>` tag would be by using javascript, which unfortunately cannot be used reliably across email clients.

The only thing I can think of is to use the inline attributes to style the element, but I haven't tested it in an email client:

```
<td onMouseOver="this.style.color='#0F0'"
   onMouseOut="this.style.color='#00F'" >
    Text
</td>
```

Try it and let me know if it helps :)

Comment: I've Tested (onMouseOver), but that Didn't help.  I Mainly desire to get the Active, Visited. Etc., Link Colors to All be the Same.  :--)

Comment: How is that code properly added to the TD coding that I already have?  :--)

Comment: For the Links, I Added a Classic HTML Code, but that Doesn't Show in the Emails.  <body link="#663399" vlink="#663399" alink="#663399">

Comment: I Edited the Code a Lot, and Removed the Link Code.  But Some Email Software Auto Converts to a Link.  :--) 
       <br><table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse: collapse; border: 5px solid #4169E1;"><tbody><tr><td style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: #FFFFFF; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><p style="color: #4169E1;">TEXT LINE 1<p style="color: #663399;">TEXT LINE 2<br>TEXT LINE 3<br>TEXT LINE 4<p style="color: #4169E1;">TEXT LINE 5</td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Please, edit your answer instead of adding a comment, it will help other who can help